# How to Remove the labels in PHPWord Charts?

Tags: php, phpword

I can't find anything in the documentation that provides for having no data labels on chart points.
The data labels provided are very nice with small numbers of data points, but with larger numbers of data points charts become too busy, and eventually illegible. Does anyone know of a way, w/o hacking the code, to achieve no data labels on PHPWord charts? Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thank you me for finding the answer and the answer is find the file Chart.php and change  
showVal and  showCatName to false
  */
    private $dataLabelOptions = array(
        'showVal'          => false, // value
        'showCatName'      => false, // category name
        'showLegendKey'    => false, //show the cart legend
        'showSerName'      => false, // series name
        'showPercent'      => false,
        'showLeaderLines'  => false,
        'showBubbleSize'   => false,
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Proper way to do it is by using `setDataLabelOptions`:

```php
$chart = $section->addChart(...);
$chart->getStyle()->setDataLabelOptions([
    'showVal' => false,
    'showCatName' => false,
]);
```